# Resolving multiple values returned from a query?

Tags: java, jdbi

While this seems like a really simple problem, the only solution I've come up with is below, any suggestions for something less ugly with lower time complexity?

My application is in Java and is retrieving with a MS-sql DB using `skife.jdbi`.

Say I have a `Table`with columns `A`, `B`, and `C` where `A` and `B` form a primary key. And I want to retrieve `C` given a particularly `A` and `B`. This is easily accomplished. But what if I my throughput requirement is very high, so I want to make these `Select` statements in batches. I end up with something like the below:

Given a `Set` of `Objects` with values `A` and `B`, I iterate the List compiling all the values of `A` and `B`. I then run a query like `SELECT A, B, C FROM tbl WHERE A IN :listOfAs AND B IN :listOfBs`. I then iterate the results of the query, matching a result to the original object by comparing the `A` and `B` value. Which all sounds reasonable, but the code ends up looking like the below, which seems ugly and suboptimal?

```
class MyObject {

  String A;
  String B;
  String C;
  Object otherData;


  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (this == other) {
      return true;
    } else if (!(other instanceof MyObject)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return A.equals(other.A) && B.equals(other.B);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return 31 * A.hashCode() + B.hashCode();
  }
}

// populates the of objects with their proper C value
void retrieveC(Set<MyObject> input) {
  Set<String> aValues = new HashSet<>();
  Set<String> bValues = new HashSet<>();

  for (MyObject object : input) {
    aValues.add(object.A);
    bValues.add(object.B);
  }

  // the dao executes the query mentioned above, and returns a Set of  
  // MyObject instances with members A, B, and C populated from the results.
  // Any results that do not contain a value for A, B, and C (which
  // shouldn't exit) are filtered out by the dao.
  Set<MyObject> results = dao.selectC(aValues, bValues);

  // ewww... O(n^2)
  for (MyObject object : input) {
    boolean resultFound = false;

    for (MyObject result : results) {
      if (object.equals(result)) {
        object.C = result.C;
        resultFound = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!resultFound) {
      // handle this case
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it that ideal would be

```
SELECT A, B, C FROM tbl WHERE A+' '+B IN :listOfAandBs
```

That is not `listOfAs x listOfBs` (quadratic complexity) but `listofAs . listOfBs` (linear, in-product)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the DAO pattern you could turn to the [fluent queries of JDBI](http://jdbi.org/fluent_queries/).

This way you could switch batching to streaming. In the example given at the JDBI page you would exchange the StringBuilder() with something that allows you to stream your results to your receiver one by one as the database returns them.

If this is possible depends of course on your development environment.